# get only the first and the last occurence from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID action Date
xxx action1 20140101
xxx action2 20140102
yyy action1 20140116
yyy action2 20140117
yyy action3 20140122
yyy action4 20140123
yyy action5 20140131
zzz action1 20140103
zzz action2 20140106
zzz action3 20140107
```

Is there a way to select 2 records for each ID (the first one and the last one)

```
xxx action1 20140101
xxx action2 20140102
yyy action1 20140116
yyy action5 20140131
zzz action1 20140103
zzz action3 20140107
```

Alternatively doing some other elaboration

```
ID firstAction Date LastAction Date
xxx action1 20140101 action2 20140102
yyy action1 20140116 action5 20140131
zzz action1 20140103 action3 20140107
```

These results can be easily reached by coding with JAVA or C++. With SQL?
First I ordered by ID and then by Date but then I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select x.ID, x.mindate as FirstActionDate, x.FirstAction as FirstAction, y.maxdate as LastActionDate, y.LastAction as LastAction
from 
(
  --FirstDate and Action 
  select a.ID, a.mindate as mindate, t.action as FirstAction 
  from 
  (

    select ID, Min(date) as mindate
     from data
     group by ID
   ) a inner join data t on a.mindate = t.date
 ) x inner join 
  (
    --Last Date And Action
    select a.ID, a.maxdate, t.action as LastAction 
    from 
    (

      select ID, max(date) as maxdate
       from data
       group by ID
     ) a inner join data t on a.maxdate = t.date
  ) y on x.ID = y.ID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc4b1/5)

Edit: I think the correct approach here is to:
(updated demo to match your sample data)

1. Get the ID and the first date (`min(date)`) and then join on the original table (`a.mindate = t.date`) to get the action name - this will give you half of the story - table `x`
2. In a similar fashion you can build table `y` to get the last date and the action
3. Finally you join them   on the `ID` column to get all the columns in single `select` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.id, t.action, t.date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SQL using the MIN and MAX aggregate functions as follows:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS FirstActionDate, MAX(Date) AS LastActionDate 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: this solution works, thanks. I'm going to test the others before marking the best answer

Comment: this solution will not give the correct first and last action

Comment: what happens if you add first/last action then?

Comment: @Serpiton why? a few random tests seem to be valid

Comment: @Davide because action1, ..., action5 seems like fake data used instead of the real one, for example if action1 is 'meeting with my boss' and action2 is 'code the query' `MIN` and `MAX` will give the wrong values, matching the first action with the second date, check this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8456d/2) to see what will happen

Comment: @Serpiton you are right, my tests were just a matter of luck.